# OKTA Widget for MFA

Tags: okta, okta-api

Is there a way to use the JS widget just for MFA?

So, we use APIs for initial authentication, if the call returns "MFA_REQUIRED".

I want then present the user with the MFA screen(s).

Answer (score 4):

It's currently undocumented, but there is a way. You can bootstrap the widget with the `stateToken` you receive from your initial primary auth request, so you can do this:

1. Make your request via the API. You will receive in the response one of the MFA statuses (i.e. MFA_REQUIRED), as well as `stateToken`.
2. Pass the `stateToken` into the widget when you initialize it:

```js
var signIn = new OktaSignIn({
  baseUrl: 'https://yourOrg.okta.com',
  stateToken: 'TheStateTokenInYourPrimaryAuthResponse',
  // any other config options you'd normally pass in
});
```

The widget will use this `stateToken` to bootstrap itself into the same state - this works for any [transaction state](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/authn.html#transaction-state).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about Okta's sign in widget http://developer.okta.com/code/javascript/okta_sign-in_widget.html#a-simple-example. Sign in widget takes care of authentication http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/authn.html#transaction-state. That includes MFA as well.

Copy paste the Sign in widget code (from above url) in a .html file and put that on your server (e.g. http://localhost:8888/login-widget.html) You can set res.session.setCookieAndRedirect to Okta org url or an app url in Okta. You . Later when you access the file and login with Okta user credentials (assuming MFA policy is active) it should prompt you for MFA. See the image below.

[image]

Comment: we do have the widget fully in use, but for some use cases we need to go to the widget and get it to start with MFA having already authenticated username/password via APIs.

Comment: Hey @martinsamm,  did you find solution for 'need to go to the widget and get it to start with MFA having already authenticated username/password via APIs' ?